# Drop temporary tables created by Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, temp-tables

I’m trying to drop temporary tables created by Redshift.
I use the following query to find all the temp tables in the cluster:

```
select name, count(distinct id)
from stv_tbl_perm
where temp = 1
group by 1
```

The table i'm trying to drop called `$stg_inappshourly`.
I've tried to drop it in both of the following methods:

```
drop table $stg_inappshourly
drop table stg_inappshourly
```

The first one returns a syntax error. The second one drops the actual table.

Any ideas how to drop it?

Comment: Why do you wish to do this? Temp tables are automatically dropped at the end of the session in which it is created.

Comment: Agreed with above comment, what is your use case? are you "cleaning up"? you can delete temp tables only within the current session that they are created though! why are you calling your temp tables by the same name as an actual table? or are you? do these tables persist after a restart? are they large in size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

The reason this table kept existing is because its session had an error and it didn't close as expected.

The only way I found to remove this table was rebooting the Redshift instance.